# Is there a simple way to solve this cubic equation?

Tags: arithmetic

The equation is as follows:

$$x-8-\frac{560}{x-32} =19\sqrt{\frac{x-8}{x-32}}$$

So first I squared everything, and then multiplied everything by $x-32$ and $(x-32)^2$ to remove fractions, but I got a really long equation with $x^5$ $x^4$ $x^3$ and $x^2$ and I couldn't solve it from there. Is there an easier way to solve this?

Comment: It's hard to know what's easiest if you haven't shared the equation you got. Maybe you made a mistake.

Comment: So the equation is not cubic, is it ?

Comment: Replace $z = (x-32)$ and solve for $z$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

multiply both sides for $(x-32)$ and then use $y=(x-8)(x-32)$ as unkown

**NOTE** be aware to verify at the end that $x\neq 32$

Equation become:

$$y-560=19 \sqrt{y} \implies y=1225$$

thus:

$$y=(x-8)(x-32)=1225 \implies x_1=-17,\quad x_2=57$$

Comment: setting $y=\sqrt{(x-8)(x-32)}$ a bit simpler. also in the end not only $x\neq 32$ but also $x\ge 32$ or $x\le 8$.

Comment: But one of the $$(x-32)$$ is under a square root

Comment: @JohnFire I've added full solution, what is not clear?

Comment: @gimusi ahh, makes sense now, thank you :)